# Retrieve options for the second drop down box from DB based on first Drop down box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on a small project. I have to retrieve some data from a DB (MySQL) and insert it into a webpage as a select (Drop Down box). The code I have written in PHP is:

```
<?php
// Connect to the db.
require ('mysqli_connect.php');

// Make the query:
$q = "SELECT employee_name from employee where dept_id=3 ORDER BY employee_id ASC"; 

// Run the query.
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if ($r) // If it ran OK, display the records. 
{ 
     echo '<select name="employee_name">';

     // Fetch and print all the records:
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
     {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['employee_name'] . '>"'.$row['employee_name'] .'</option>';

     }
         echo "</select>";    

}

mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.
mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
?>
```

When I execute the query in MySQL console, it returns the correct output. [It is a list of five names].

Can you help me find the error?

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing if you are receiving the correct output?

Comment: In the PHP code, I get a simple drop down box with no content when I need a drop down box with the list of the names. <img src="http://imgur.com/1oiMKet">

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors with @ in front of mysqli_query?  It sounds like you're returning an empty result.  Lacking any error, that's the only thing that seems to make sense.

Comment: @BarryDevSF : I stopped suppressing errors. Still, No errors and no Output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if ($r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q))
{
    echo 'select ....
```

As `$r` is different to `true` on `SELECT` queries.

**EDIT**

You are closing the `select` tag on every iteration of the `while`. Try it like this:

```
if ($r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q))
{ 
     echo '<select name="employee_name">';
     // Fetch and print all the records:
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
     {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['employee_name'] . '>"'.$row['employee_name'] .'</option>';
     }
     echo "</select>";                         
//   ^
//   |__  Now the </select> is out of the loop
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Running within an if statement???? And, what difference does it make from the existing code.

Comment: Even with this correction, I still get an empty drop down box. I don't have any content in it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Echo your end select out of the loop.

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
 {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['employee_name'] . '>"'.$row['employee_name'] .'</option>';

 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Oops. That was wrong. But, still, I get only an empty drop down box.  <img src = http://imgur.com/TLyMRF1/>

Comment: Check the drop-down on the html page and see if there is any data in there. if so, then try adding selected to an option. <option value='whatever' selected>

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. I am trying to insert the data obtained from the db (through the query) into the drop down box